# Angular HttpClient get do text, not json

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am trying to disable automated response parsing into `json` for my `get` request in my `HttpClient` following the [API](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/6c1ab479ee07c9e80afefbb1c50d8fb000c7a9fa/packages/common/http/src/client.ts#L934). However, every time I set

```
return this.http.get(requestURL, {
  responseType: 'text'
}).pipe(
  map((response: Response) => {
    console.log(response);
  })
);
```

my VSCode terminal flares up the `pipe` and including bracket in red and I get

```
error TS2345: Argument of type 'OperatorFunction<Response, void>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<string, void>'
```

??? I am following the documentation. Am I on the wrong version?

------ EDIT ------

After suggestion below I get this

```
map((response: Response) => {
    return this.parseData(response.text());
})

error TS2345: Argument of type 'Promise<string>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
```

[ng]       Type 'Response' is not assignable to type 'string'.
Did you forget to use 'await'?

Where `parseData` takes string as input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that you are not returning anything from the RxJS operator [map](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/map). At minimum you would need to return `response`:

```
return this.http.get(requestURL, {
  responseType: 'text'
}).pipe(
  map((response: Response) => {
    console.log(response);
    return response;
  })
);
```

This would be similar to `Array.prototype.map` and were not returning anything, you'd likely have some sort of compile error in terms of TypeScript.

Realistically, you do not need `map` at all here as it used for transforming/projecting/mapping the emitted values. If you are trying to do side-effect operations such as `console.log()`, you should use an operator such as [tap](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/tap) instead:

```
return this.http.get(requestURL, {
  responseType: 'text'
}).pipe(
  tap((response) => {
    console.log(response);
  })
);
```

**Update:**
It sounds like you are receiving a new error regarding trying to pass a `Promise<string>` to a function that expects just `string`. This is coming from `response.text()`. If you absolutely need to execute method `text()`, you can use an operator such as [switchMap](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/switchMap) to resolve the promise:

```
return this.http.get(requestURL, {
  responseType: 'text'
}).pipe(
  switchMap((response) => response.text()),
  map((text) => this.parseData(text))
);
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Thanks! Please see my follow up edits above. I initially had a parse function for the custom data that comes in. However, not I get another one.

Comment: @ElDude The error is saying parse text expects a string but you are passing a promise. Is response already text when it gets to the map operator? If so you may just be able to pass response to the helper function. If you must execute text() then you’d need to resolve that first which can be done with another operator such as switchMap. I can show if you have issues with that.

Comment: @ElDude I've updated the answer to show how you can use another RxJS operator such as `switchMap` to execute and resolve `text()` so that it can be passed into `parseData()`.

Comment: Thanks! Looks better now but now it parses the string char by char ... lol. :D

Comment: Turns out I had to remove your suggested `switchMap` and just change my code to `map((response: string) => ...)` to get it to work. Thank you so much for your help!